# 2D 'fill' for 3D helix

Tags: plotting, graphics, parametric-functions

I have made a simple helix using ParametricPlot3D:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[x], Cos[x], x}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

I want to add a a continuous 'fill' connecting the curve to the line `y=0, z=0` (in other words, the `x` axis). The result should look something like an Archimedes screw.

It seems to me that this should be simple, but I can't find anything telling me how. Suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps this may help_http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ArchimedeanScrew/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[x], r Sin[x], x}, {x, 0, 10}, {r, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Note that it's better to use also a `Sin` if you'd like to have a true helix...